# I cannot download Octave statistics package using either Macport or 'pkg install' code in Octave

Tags: octave

I've started learning MATLAB trough Octave. I wanted to use statistics functions and for that I found out that I need package statistics of Octave. So basically I'm totally new to all of these stuffs. I tried out downloading it using Macport and Octave pkg install code, but couldn't do it.

```
    yunsangbin-ui-MacBook:~ carpediem$ sudo port install octave-statistics
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for octave-statisticsWarning: All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable; defaulting to first fallback option
Warning: All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable; defaulting to first fallback option
Warning: All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable; defaulting to first fallback option
Warning: All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable; defaulting to first fallback option
Warning: All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable; defaulting to first fallback option
Warning: All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable; defaulting to first fallback option
Warning: All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable; defaulting to first fallback option
Warning: All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable; defaulting to first fallback option
Warning: All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable; defaulting to first fallback option
Warning: All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable; defaulting to first fallback option
Warning: All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable; defaulting to first fallback option
Warning: All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable; defaulting to first fallback option
Warning: All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable; defaulting to first fallback option
Warning: All compilers are either blacklisted or unavailable; defaulting to first fallback option


Error: Dependency 'mpich-clang14' not found.
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets if you believe there is a bug.
Error: Processing of port octave-statistics failed
```

which is the result of using terminal, and the bottom is from octave

```
>> pkg install -forge statistics
configure: error: in `/var/folders/1f/x6s2z7hj6yd_pb9j3dcww_kw0000gn/T/oct-0wOpAt/statistics-1.4.3/src':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no

error: pkg: error running the configure script for statistics.
error: called from
    configure_make at line 93 column 9
    install at line 196 column 7
    pkg at line 568 column 9

>> pkg list
Package Name  | Version | Installation directory
--------------+---------+-----------------------
          io  |   2.6.4 | /Users/carpediem/Library/Application Support/Octave.app/6.2.0/pkg/io-2.6.4
```

I have no idea to solve this. what should I do?

Comment: `checking whether the C compiler works... no` Did you install the Xcode command line tools?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I definitely did.

Comment: Since it doesn't work, I suggest you reinstall it. Try running it from the command line, see if it prompts you for something when you start it up.

Comment: After I made sure that I downloaded macports  and command line tool, I tried 'sudo port install octave' . But it didn't work again, saying 'Error: Dependency 'mpich-clang14' not found.' exactly same error like above. Anyway thank you for trying to help me out. I'll just figure it out to solve it other way

Comment: I really think your Xcode installation is either not there or broken. Try `xcode-select --install`. If that doesn't install the tools, delete the installation with `rm -rf \`xcode-select -p\``, then try installing it again.

Comment: I solved the problem! Thank you so much. I reinstalled xcode and command tool in developer website of apple and it worked to run the code I tried at the first to download statistics package.

Comment: Note for future readers: In addition to installing Xcode and/or the Xcode Command Line Tools, you usually also need to _run_ it once and accept the EULA (or do command-line magic to do the same) before Xcode will actually function when being called as a command from other programs, like Octave. The symptoms of that problem look just like this. Run Xcode by double-clicking it, click the "OK" or "Accept" button on the license dialog that pops up, quit Xcode, and try again, and it'll maybe/probably work. Frickin' Apple, amirite?